# how to get the type from my database

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I'm Using asp.net, vb.net and sql-server.

I have  table called "Login" which contains username, password and type.
Depending on the type, a page redirection will occur.

My system have admin, student and instructor. Each one has his own pages and controls.

How do I get the type from the table based on the username (I will take it from the textbox when the user types it and click login)?

Thanks

Comment: How are you now checking the password is ok? (maybe that code can be modified to give the "type" also)

Answer (score 3):

Validate password & fetch type from your database using a SQL Query. Something like

```
select username,user_type from myTable where username='john' AND password='abc';
```

Now on your login page, you can fetch the type value through your data layer & redirect user to a page based on his role. This is just rough but you get the idea

```
string user_type, string userName;
//Execute data reader
if(myReader.Read())
{
    userName= myReader[0].ToString(); // you can also make a class
    userType=myReader[1].ToString();  // you can also store these values in Session
}
// Close connection etc.

switch (userType)
{
   case "admin":
                 Response.Redirect("~/admin/Default.aspx"); break;

   case "user":
                 Response.Redirect("~/public/Default.aspx"); break; 

   case default:
                // Redirect to your default page for default user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a field in the table where you store the user details called *UserType*
So when a person logs in from your login page, you simply would have to get this value too. And then you can use switch case to redirect to different pages.

Comment: good answer but I have Type field already 
my qust is how to get this value from the data base
dose it need any method to get it or what

Comment: I guess others have answered it with better details. Please refer them. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Query might look like this:

```
   SELECT
        UserType
    FROM 
        Login
    WHERE
        username = @your_username
```

You can put this in a function or stored procedure, and call it from app, while providing parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `RecordSet` object in your `ASP.NET` page.
Use the query for opening into this recordset:

```
SELECT username, 
       password, 
       type 
  FROM login 
 WHERE userid = @yourUserID
   AND password = @yourUserPassword
```

Then check in your `ASP.NET` page with a `SWITCH CASE` construct on the `TYPE` column.